# Integrating an external pure Java library and having Android classes access on it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, shared-libraries

I'm having troubles trying to get my external Java project so I can use Android classes on it as well. The library is already integrated on the Android project. For instance: I have several model classes on it that I would want to implement `Parcelable` so they can be seriallized accordingly, but none of the Android classes are available on them.

**Clarification** I only did this in order to try to solve the issue

So far I've only tried:

- Changing and matching the external library's package:

**Package name in Android**

`com.domain.androidproject`

**Library's package originally**

`com.domain.libproject`

Changed to:

`com.dommain.androidproject.libproject`

But no luck so far. I imported the library as a Gradle external project vía:

```
compile project(path: ':LibProject')
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unclear on the question... why would you need to change package names at all? This is an external dependency, so why can't you just import it and use it?

Comment: Because I did it that way originally but didnt work

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? What happened when you tried? What Christopher suggested is the correct way to go about this, and if you have a problem with it, that's the problem you should solve (solving the problem at it's core) rather than creating a bunch of bridges and wrappers.

Comment: What I mean by doesn't work is what is says in the question: I cannot import classes from Android

Comment: Wow, okay, nice attitude. I was obviously asking about the errors your IDE prompted which prevented it, information that could actually help you solve the issue. But if you wanna pollute your API with a nasty work around, go for it.

Comment: Dude, I don't know what the problem is, sorry if I hurt your feelings by answering and thank you for your thoughts

Comment: @VinceEmigh I know you are getting used to shit-ass quality posts. But if there would''ve been any IDE error I would've shown it. No warnings, no errors, no nothing. Just can't import Android classes inside that directory

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to define a binding between your pure java library and android. You could use Dependency injection to inject the models using the class signature, and then define the parcelable models inside the app (or into another project, like a plugin). Or you could achieve the same using generics. keep in mind, since the java library is already compiled, technically, you can't change it by importing it into the android project (I've seen people "rewriting" some files from a dependency and then adding them with the whole original path to fool the classpath, but that's highly risky since you are not gonna be able to interact with the rest of the dependency's code and if something changes, the thing will break).

if you have access to the pure java's library sourcecode, then modify it to use factories or providers of models. If not, extend the models, add parcelable support, and attempt to use those instead of the original model classes.

Example:

let's suppose we have a model and some functions using it:

```
public class myModel{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    //more getters and setters
}

public interface myModelCreator<T>{
    public myModel create(T toModel);
    public T uncreate(myModel fromModel);
}

public static void doSomething(myModel model){
    //some library operations
}
```

Now, in the android project:

```
public class myAndroidModel extends myModel implements Parcelable{
    /*Implements the parcelable methods using the class accessors, or you can change the myModel members to protected.*/
}

public class myAndroidModelCreator implements myModelCreator<myAndroidModel>{

    @Override
    public myModel create(myAndroidModel toModel){
        //create the myModel using the parcelable class.
    }

    @Override    
    public myAndroidModel uncreate(myModel fromModel){
        //reverse operation.
    }

}
```

Now, in the android project, you can use the parcelable subclass everywhere, and everytime you need to call the library, you can supply the creator interface using the parcelables as arguments. 
Another alternative would be changing the library method signatures to something like this:

```
public static void<T extends myModel> doSomething(T model){
    //some library operations
}
```

So you can directly consume the parcelable subclasses. But depending on your hierarchy, that may be not possible. Lastly, you could attempt to implement dependency injection into the java project using Guice and Roboguice in the android project. Since roboguice uses guice, it is possible they can interoperate, but that's a long shot.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The library is not compiled, I have the source code and can change it at will. But what you describe sounds awful complicated just to make a class implement an interface. I'd appreciate if you describe further or point me to a tut where I can check that out.

Comment: To clarify: I understand your second thought but not the first one

Comment: I will try this out today and will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like [Fco P.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099343/94363)'s answer, but for the sake of completness, here is an alternative answer.

Use json to serialize objects, rather than `Parcelable`. You can then put your serialized json as a string extra in intent or as string in bundles.

- it's faster to implement than using Parcelable, with libraries such as [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) or [Square moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi).
- it's less performant than Parcelable

Comment: How do I go around using `Bundle.putParcelable()` with your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Generally if you want to make use of classes in another project/library:

File -> New -> Import Module -> Navigate to the directory of an old project/Library -> Ok

Check off the modules you want to import -> OK

Right click the app module -> Open Module Settings -> dependencies -> + -> Module -> The new Module.

Your project should then be usable in whatever project you just did that for.

Comment: Please let me know if I'm not explaining myself correctly on the question. What I want is to be able to use Android classes inside that project, not the other way around.

Comment: The development kits likely will prevent that. When Java is built around jdk, android is built around the android sdk which includes a jdk. So you can implement java in an Android project but not Android specific code in a Java library without configuring your environment to also use Android. Out of curiosity what makes you want to do that?

Comment: Like I said, I want model classes from that project to be able to use `Parcelable`. The project is already imported and lives on its own directory, but I can't import any classes from Android inside it. I know it's just easier to just copy those classes into a module's directory but I think it would not be practical.

Comment: Well the other way is to extend those classes and implement parcelable which is not exactly practical either... I think the best way would be to make a separate Android Library project and rework it once that way next time you can just use that Android Library. But again you can make a parcelable implementation on the polymorphic classes.

Answer (score -1):

Create an android library project with packagename com.domain.libproject

Copy all the sources in src folder.

Update jar dependencies in build.gradle and after that you can make your class in the library parcelable.

Let me know if any issues.

Best regds