# How Import android.graphics.Bitmap in jar file

Tags: java, android, jar, aar

I know that The main difference between a Jar and a AAR is that AARs include resources such as layouts, drawables and etc. I want create a Jar file that includes the Bitmap class.Is this possible or not ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

when I import andorid.graphics.Bitmap in classes in Jar File Android Studio 
shows error:Cannot resolve symbol 'Bitmap','BitmapFactory' 'Context'and ..
[image]

I Follow these steps to build Jar File:

File > New > New Module > java library

I know how to use the library and I know that andorid api classes like Bitmap available in AAR (also in AAR file available resource file)
my problem is the use android api classes in JAR File.

Comment: `android.graphics.Bitmap` is an Android framework class. Neither a JAR nor an AAR would "include" it. What do you mean by "that includes the Bitmap class"?

Comment: you can create your jar with only own classes, that may be using `Bitmap` or any Android API class.

Comment: @CommonsWare means when I use the android.graphics.Bitmap in classes in jar file andorid studio display error : Cannot resolve symbol 'Bitmap'

Comment: Add `import android.graphics.Bitmap`, as you have in your question. If you cannot import anything from `android`, then you are compiling against the standard JDK, not Android. Usually, I create an AAR, rather than a JAR, when I am writing Android-specific libraries, as then this stuff works "out of the box".

Comment: @AbhishekAryan when I import andorid.graphics.Bitmap in classes in Jar File Android Studio shows error:Cannot resolve symbol 'Bitmap','BitmapFactory' 'Context'and .. But in AAr File every things is ok

Comment: @hamidrezahaajhoseini Look at [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-backend-android/1.9.6), this is a jar , Inside this jar there is a [class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/APKExpansionSupport.java) that is using Context of Android API, that mean you can use Andoid API class inside jars

Comment: @AbhishekAryan thank u
Is the problem in my case the JDK as  CommonsWare said ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I've updated my question please look at it

Answer (score -1):

You can create your `.jar` with own classes, that may be using `Bitmap` or any Android API class.

This is a file `BitmapHelper.java`

```
package com.its.test;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class BitmapHelper {

    public static void getBitmap(String fileName){
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

Jar file is just a zip file having number of `.class` file, so `BitmapHelper.class` file is inside my `.jar`

When we need to use that `.jar` just add it in build path so that it compile.

Or in gradle project put your `.jar` inside `libs` folder and compile in this way

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

If you deployed your `.jar` in local/remote maven repo or any other you can compile by using `group name`, `artifact` and `version` of that artifact.

> The main difference between a Jar and a AAR is that AARs include
>   resources such as layouts, drawables etc. This makes it a lot easier
>   to create self-contained visual components. For example if you have
>   multiple apps that use the same login screen, with Jars you could
>   share classes but not the layout, styles, etc., you still had to
>   duplicate them. With AARs everything is bundled in one neat package.

**EDIT**

Java Library is different from `.jar`,  library is a collection of jars. You can easily integrate `.jars` into android project but if you want to add Java library than you need to define a binding between your pure java library and the android.

You can check this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42099343/3445320

Comment: Adding "import android.graphics.Bitmap;" does not solve the problem, this is the problem, adding it gets "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Your answer should include how to include dependence to android sdk to resolve "android.graphics.Bitmap" in a Java Library (compiles to Jar).